# Can diopters be added for glasses? or is it more complicated?

Tags: optics, lenses

I am using glasses for myopia and in the past couple years I've been adding reading glasses for when I'm on the computer. The reading glasses add +0.75.
I wear one pair on top of each other! it's not super comfortable but it works and looks funny as a bonus.

I was thinking about getting a pair of computer glasses, but because of the pandemic I'm not very keen on  the idea of having the optometrist breathing right in my face during an eye check.

Since my prescription is L:-5.25 / R:-3.50, can I simply add the +0.75 directly and order glasses with -4.50 / -2.75?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focal lenght  combination law of two thin lenses is addition of diopter minus quadratic reduction by distance

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{f_1}+\frac{1}{f_2}-\frac{d}{f_1 f_2}$$

For myopia with focal length of 0.4 m  and distance eye-glas 0.02m for a correction to 10m eg

$$  1/(1/f_e - 1/f_g +  0.02/(f_e*f_g)) == 10 \to 1/g= 2.52632$$

Correct instead to 1m screen distance

$$  1/(1/f_e - 1/f_g +  0.02/(f_e*f_g)) == 1 \to 1/g= 1.57895$$

For laptops work its better to correct for 0.5m yielding 0.526316.

So the absolute value of no great importance, reduce the diopter by something between 1 and 2. With 0.75 its even possible to view the TV at the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to send in your existing prescription and get them to add .75 diopters to it. If you can, that also would work. For weak lenses like glasses that are right up against each other, adding the strengths is a good approximation to use.

One pair on top of the other is not an unusual thing for people to do. As you say, it works, and it is cheap and easy. I have done it myself.

If you can't get a variation on your prescription and your prescription includes myopia, I suggest you continue doing that until you can get a fresh prescription. Myopia is caused by eye lenses with an odd shape. This causes defects in vision that vary across the visual field. An odd shape is built into the glasses to counteract this. if you order stronger glasses without the myopia correction, you probably wouldn't be happy with them.

Comment: I definitely need the myopia correction. At least that part hasn't changed in the last 20+ years. So I can request (-5.25 + 0.75) = -4.5 for example?

Comment: Thomas, they're a bit expensive, but you can get a gradient lens for your myopia, whereby the bottom of the lens gradually changes to a lower power.  In effect, such a lens would work like bifocals, but there wouldn't be a sharp change of power in the lens (and no visible line in it).